# Why is a variable type mismatching in a tuple but not in a function?

Tags: c++, for-loop, range

I have a function defined like this

```
void helper(float a, Example &e, Example f) {
    // this function will alter some values in 'e' w.r.t 'a'.
}
```

I have another function defined like this

```
void helperList (Example &e, Example f) {
    std::vector<std::tuple<float, Example, Example>> someVariable;
    auto some_1 = std::make_tuple( 0.4, e, f);
    someVariable.push_back(some_1);

    for (auto element : someVariable){
         std::apply (helper, element);
    }

    helper (0.4, e, f);
}
```

What I expected was both

```
for (auto element : someVariable){
     std::apply (helper, element);
}
```

and

```
helper (0.4, e, f);
```

to have same effect of e but while just calling helper works as I expected, that for loop doesn't modify e which I thought was due to

```
std::vector<std::tuple<float, Example, Example>> someVariable;
```

not being like this

```
std::vector<std::tuple<float, Example &, Example>> someVariable;
```

But if I do that, push_back errors out with this message no matching member function for call to 'push_back'

I'm not sure what could be going wrong. Help is appreciated!

Comment: `for (auto element : someVariable){` -> `for (auto &element : someVariable){`. I'm sure there's a plethora of dupes out there that I can't seem to find with a quick search.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  `for (auto element : someVariable)` makes a copy of every element in the vector.  You need `for (auto& element : someVariable)` to get a reference to every element.

Comment: @scohe001 I don't think that's the problem. someVariable is already holding a copy of e. Doing what you suggest won't modify e.

Comment: Hmm you're right @zdan, they'd also have to change to `std::vector<std::tuple<float, Example&, Example>>` and use `std::make_tuple (.4, std::ref(e),f);`. I think the crux is still that references instead of values are needed though, so the dupe still stands.

Comment: Please post the exact error message and tell us what compiler you are using. The types in the tuple of the `push_back` call must match the types of the tuple in the vector declaration.

Comment: `std::make_tuple(0.4, e , f)` is resulting in a tuple of type `std::tuple<double, Example, Example>` and this might be causing you trouble